JavaScript Date object showing incorrect date when set to midnight in UTC
I'm encountering an issue with the JavaScript Date object where it's showing an incorrect date when I set it to midnight in UTC. Here's my code:
function updateDates(startDate) {
    var utcStartDate = startDate + 'T00:00:00Z';
    var currentDate = new Date(utcStartDate);

    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(currentDate);

    // Additional code to update dates in the UI
}


Here is console:
2024-02-26
list:4600 Sun Feb 25 2024 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

I expect currentDate to represent the date specified by startDate at midnight in the UTC time zone. However, when I log currentDate, it's showing a date one day earlier than expected, along with a time that doesn't match midnight.
For example, if startDate is '2024-02-26', I expect currentDate to be February 26, 2024, at midnight in UTC. Instead, I'm getting February 25, 2024, at 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time).
I've tried setting the time zone offset to UTC ('Z'), but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. It's worth noting that this discrepancy occurs regardless of the local time zone settings of the environment.
I would appreciate any insights into why the Date object behaves this way and how I can ensure consistent results across different environments. Thank you!

Try Date.UTC()

new Date(Date.UTC(utcStartDate)), like this? it's not working

Not quite. If you check the documentation in the link you can see that Date.UTC needs individual time period arguments

var dateComponents = startDate.split('-');
var year = parseInt(dateComponents[0], 10);
var month = parseInt(dateComponents[1], 10) - 1;
var day = parseInt(dateComponents[2], 10);
var currentDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0));
I tried this. but still not woring.


Please edit the question to include the code as it's very hard to read in comments. 2. Please give more detail than 'not working'. What happens? What errors are shown in the console? What's the value of startDate etc. The more information you can give us, the better we can debug your problem.


The result is 'Sun Feb 25 2024 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)'.
But I expect the result like 'Mon Feb 26 2024 00:00:00 GMT+1'

why? midnight 26 feb 2024 IS 25 feb in your timezone since you are west of GMT - try using + 'T24:00:00Z';

Your issue is that you don't seem to understand timezone offsets. You're creating a Date for 2024-02-26T00:00:00Z then creating a timestamp for UTC-8, so of course it's 8 hours earlier than the UTC time, i.e. 2024-02-25T16:00:00GMT-08:00. It's right there in the timestamp you posted.

As @JaromandaX says, the two timestamps (2024-02-26T00:00:00Z and 2024-02-25T16:00:00GMT-08:00) represent exactly the same instant in time, just with different offsets. Note that UTC is not a timezone, it's a time standard. The equivalent timezone (more or less) is GMT.

The problem that your date is constructed properly as a UTC one, you can check that with toUTCString(). But unfortunately all Date's methods works with local time like Date#getHours(), Date#toString().
What you want is probably your local time at midnight that you INTERPRET later as an UTC date. That way all Date's methods would return proper times you expect.
Just remove 'Z' in the end, that way your timezone isn't involved in the parsing:


function updateDates(startDate) {
    var utcStartDate = startDate + 'T00:00:00';
    var currentDate = new Date(utcStartDate)

    console.log(startDate);
    console.log(currentDate.toString());

    // Additional code to update dates in the UI
}

updateDates('2024-04-26');



What I usually do:

When data comes from a backend - convert all UTC date strings to local Dates
When I post data to a backend - convert all local Dates to UTC strings.

All this is done automatically with API call hooks.

If the intention is to set midnight UTC, this code fails to do so. It sets midnight whatever-local-time-zone. You can decide to ignore the time zone altogether and pretend it's UTC, but it isn't, so you'll eventually find issues with e.g. daylight saving time.

@ÁlvaroGonzález i think the OP whats the midnight in the local time. the OP could misunderstand that

Re "JS dates are always kind of local". No they aren't, they're always kind of UTC (because all they contain is a millisecond offset from the ECMAScript epoch, which is specified in UTC). It's Date.prototype.toString that returns a localised timestamp (as do other methods like toLocaleString, toDateString, etc.).

To create a Date for the local 0 hrs would require something like let [y, m, d] = startDate.split(/\D/); let date = new Date(y, m-1, d).

@RobG you are right about the UTC offset, but unfortunately a date behaves mostly as local, i've added some more explanation to the description. At least that POV helps me to manage dates better

Yes, it's the (non–UTC) methods that are localised. ;-)

The date is always stored in terms of UTC but while displaying the browser converts it to the local timezone. You can use .toISOString() to get the time in UTC.
More info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString
function updateDates(startDate) {
var utcStartDate = startDate + 'T00:00:00Z';
var currentDate = new Date(utcStartDate);

console.log(startDate);
console.log(currentDate.toISOString());

// Additional code to update dates in the UI

}

Given a date format of '2024-04-26', there's no need to add "T00:00:00Z" as it's parsed as UTC anyway (which might be considered a bug in the specification, but it's not going to change). ;-)

Thank you. Neeraja Tokekar.
